# Azure Data Factory Copy Data from Rest API to CSV - Json object value isn't output

Tags: json, rest, azure-data-factory

The values for data.CustomerNumber do not get written to the file, the other elements do.
The CustomerNumber is Pascal case because it is a custom value in the system I am pulling the data out of.

[image: Sample of Json coming back from API]

I have tried the map complex values option, advanced editor, deleted, started over. I originally was trying to save this to a Azure Sql table but gave up , and just tried to write to a file. I have been able to do this type of mapping in other pipelines so I am really at a loss for why it doesn't work in this case.
[image: Mapping in the copy data task]

The actual json content for the mapping
[image]

Comment: You have given a mapping JSON content. Is that the one you are expecting to get the desired result or you have that JSON?

Comment: That mapping Json is what it currently shows when you view the source code